# How to migrate a 2007 sharepoint list to 2010?

Tags: 2007, migration, list, excel

We have a list in sharepoint 2007 that we need to move to another site which is based on sharepoint 2010.

what's the best and fastest method?

thanks in advance

Comment: I tried exporting the list and importing it in 2010 but didn't work because 2007 export an "STP" file while 2010 is "WSP" and they're not compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it.

the best way is to export the list to a spreadsheet in 2007 and then import that xslx file in 2010.
I found this article very useful:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349-3bb6-4087-94f4-7f95ff4ca81f&ID=91

by the way, I faced a problem when exporting to excel if the site is using forms based authentication with the error message: "Excel Cannot access sharepoint list"

one more thing, Make sure you have the fields visible in the view before you export to spreadsheet since non-visible fields will NOT be included.

Answer (score 5):

If you read this [article](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2010/11/17/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-migrate-a-single-list-from-sp-2007-to-sp-2010.aspx) by Thao Nguyen at Bamboo Solutions you will find 4 different methods for migrating a list from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010.  My preferred method is number 1:

Method 1 - Migrate a single list from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 using a list template

1. Save the list as a list template (".stp" file).
2. Download the list template
3. Change the extension to ".cab" and extract the contents
4. Edit the manifest.xml file changing ProductVersion element from 3 to 4
5. Repackage the STP file.
6. Upload the STP file to your SharePoint 2010 site
7. Create a new list using the template.

This works well for me becacuse I can write a bit of powershell to automate most of the process.

Comment: Where exactly is the list supposed to be updated to?

Comment: if like rick your confused about repackaging than you need to look at makecan.exe , you would do the changes as noted but when repackaging get the new manifest plus the other files... put in a folder and follow http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sekharevani/archive/2012/08/31/cabinet-file-with-multiple-files.aspx now you can rename the cab file back to stp and follow this http://www.techgrowingpains.com/2010/01/how-to-add-a-stp-template-to-an-existing-sharepoint-site/

Comment: Just to let everyone know, I followed these instructions way back in the day. However, we are now trying to upgrade document libraries from SP2010 --> SP2013 that were created by such a template, and the upgrade process isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I just had good success using Microsoft Access to move a list from a SharePoint 2007 site to a SharePoint 2010 site.

**Steps:**

1. I opened Access 2010, and created a blank database.
2. Under the External Data tab on the ribbon, under the More drop down, I selected Import or link to a SharePoint list.
3. In the Get External Data pop-up, I entered the URL of the SP 2007 site that held the list and selected the "Import the source data into a new table in the current database" and pressed Next.
4. On the next screen I selected my list, and selected "All Columns" for Items to import.
5. Now the list is in a table in the database. The table has the same title as the list.
6. Right-click on the new table, select Export, select SharePoint list, and enter the destination site (SP 2010)

Answer (score 1):

For upgrading the list templates (being migrated from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010) either you have to manually upgrade them by hand or using some PowerShell to upgrade them. Even if you upgrade them using PowerShell, there is no way to automatically upload (the upgraded template) them back to the site collections where they belong to:

I have done the PowerShell which performs the following 4 tasks:

1. Get a URL to a certain Web application in SharePoint environment (Specify the URL in `Config.xml`)
2. The code tries to find all List Templates within all site collections and download them all on the disk (in their separate folders i.e. for each site collection a separate folder is created)
3. Upgrade the List templates using the PowerShell
4. Upload them back to their original site collections
5. I assume the PowerShell code will be run on 2010 upgraded SharePoint sites.

**Full code can be downloaded from CodePlex:** https://upgradelisttemplates.codeplex.com/

**Technet Gallery:** http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Upgrade-List-Templates-0b86f443

**Blog**: http://falakmahmood.blogspot.se/2013/02/upgrade-list-templates-from-sharepoint.html