# Import Data only from SharePoint List to another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list

Basically I'm trying to migrate my SP2007 site to SP2010 for Which I migrated all the list, Libraries and worklfows everything. Now I want to update my data in 2010 environment for which I just want to export data from 2007 List and import data into new 2010 site list.

I've tried to export and import using excel but I was unable to do so because it was exporting only that data which defined in a view and then I created a new View "all Requests" with all columns selected and then I tried the same but it was not able to open in excel file as the files says unexpected error has occurred.

Now can any one help me around with this data migration. Is there any other way around to migrate data. Because excel is unable to open/read my data

I've migrated my list using the following [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/how-to-migrate-a-2007-sharepoint-list-to-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Migrate a single list from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 using a list template

1.Save the list as a list template (".stp" file) "with include content" .

2.Download the list template.

3.Change the extension to ".cab" and extract the contents.

4.Edit the manifest.xml file changing ProductVersion element from 3 to 4.

5.Repackage the STP file.

6.Upload the STP file to your SharePoint 2010 site.

7.Create a new list using the template.

Try this. May be it will work for you. I found this solution [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/how-to-migrate-a-2007-sharepoint-list-to-2010).

Comment: I've already done this step as I mentioned in my question. I've created the list with same steps I've configured all the things including workflows and webparts on that list. I just want to update my data of that list now.

Comment: if I do the same it will say list already exists can I do the same which will import data only?

Comment: If your newly created list is not having any current live data, then you can delete this list and try to import the list data as mentioned above. Don't forget to tick checkbox of "include content".

Comment: No I can't do this, as I've made some configurations on list i.e assigning workflow to it, assigning webpart to it and created view of it.